Wrong Pandas timezone conversion using .tz_convert()
I'm using Pandas' Series.dt.tz_convert() method to do timezone conversion on a DataFrame Series:
STANDARD_DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format=STANDARD_DATETIME_FORMAT).dt.tz_convert(timezone)

Works fine for the majority of timezones, but not for some, like "America/Mexico_City" (UTC-6).
For example, the date:
"2024-04-24 10:00:00.000000+0000"
with timezone="America/Mexico_City" outputs:
"2024-04-24 05:00:00"
instead of
"2024-04-24 04:00:00"
Mexico City is not on Daylight Saving Time for the given date, so that's not the issue.
Pandas version is 1.2.0.

agreed with @MGP that this is a version issue. timezone rules get updated from time to time. However it's not actually pandas that provides the tz data here; you'll have to ensure that pytz (older versions of pandas) and tzdata (on Windows) packages are up-to-date.

You are using a quite old version of Pandas. It was released on 26th December 2020
Your link suggests that Mexico City changed its DST usage in 2023. It's possible that at the time, Pandas devs didn't know about plans to change it.
Edit: It works correctly in the current Pandas version (2.2.2).

Thanks! I thought about that possibility regarding Pandas version, but with your confirmation I will definitely update the Lambda Layer. I'll bring updates.
